# Steps to unit test a strong-named class library

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, code-signing, strongname

On a Windows 7 64 bit machine I have a solution with a class library which has two snk files: "AcmePublic.snk" and "key.snk"

The project properties Signing tab does not have the "Sign the assembly" checkbox checked but the "AcmePublic.snk" is visible in the key file dropbox (greyed out).

These lines are in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("AcmePublic.snk")]
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true)]
```

The solution builds.

I have added a class library using the NUnit NuGet package. To this test project I have copied the same Project Properties Signing setup (unchecked but with "AcmePublic.snk" selected) and added the two AssemblyInfo.cs lines - after copying the .snk files into the test project. I have, of course, added a reference to the library project into the test project and created a test which attempts to instantiate one of the classes.

At this point the solution will build but the test throws this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly AcmeData.Test or one of it's dependencies. Strong name could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with...
```

At this point I check the "Sign the assembly" checkbox in both project Signing tabs and rebuild. The "AcmePublic.snk" file is selected in each. The solution builds but I get the same error when running the test.

I now select "key.snk" and re-check the "Sign the assembly" checkbox in both projects, rebuild and rerun the test. Same error.

So, now I set both the project properties to "AcmePublic.snk", uncheck "Sign the assembly", and comment out this line in both AssemblyInfo.cs files:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true)]
```

Bear in mind the AssemblyInfo.cs still has this line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("AcmePublic.snk")]
```

The solution fails to build, with this error:

```
Key file 'AcmePublic.snk' is missing the private key needed for signing
```

Now I re-check the "Sign the assembly" checkboxes and ensure that "key.snk" is selected in both dropdowns. Rebuild. Builds ok.

Run test. Error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Dapper' or one of it's dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required.
```

This error from a line in the class library, not the test project.

What do I do?

How should I set up a class library project to be used as a NuGet package (albeit internally) and have an NUnit test project while the class library uses Dapper?

Comment: Why are you trying to make your test strong-named? There's no need to do that.

Comment: Because the library it is testing is strongly named.

Comment: Again... there's no need to do that. A strongly named assembly cannot reference a weakly named assembly but there is no problem with the reverse. The only time you would need to give your test assembly a strong name is if you want to make internals visible to it.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I had not inferred your original meaning, thanks for the clarification.